# Response is not appearing in chrome Developer Tool but Dynamic Form data is posting for the next request

Tags: google-chrome, jmeter

i recorded script with jmeter for 4 transactions.launch, logon, continue, logoff. i am seeing redirecting error for continue transaction and for that i am not seeing any response for that all request. But i am seeing response data in jmeter for all request for continue transaction. i have id token value and that i want to substitute for the next request as post.

Continue transaction

1. request..response (i am seeing response data with **ID_token** in jmeter but not in browser)
2. request (ID_Token as posting here) - Need to get final response for continue transaction.

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [Redirections in HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) guide:

   > In HTTP, redirection is triggered by a server sending a special redirect response to a request. Redirect responses have [status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) that start with 3, and a [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header holding the URL to redirect to.
2. As per [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html) the response body is not required for 3xx redirect responses, moreover for [304 Not Modified](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-10.3.5) status it's even forbidden so it's absolutely fine to not to have response body for 3xx status codes as long as you have Location header which points you to the next page.

Just make sure that JMeter sends the same requests and they're treated in the same manner by the server as requests from the real browser by comparing request flow in your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and the ones which are sent by JMeter. In case of mismatch play with `Redirect automatically` and `Follow redirects` checkboxes in [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler or in [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) configuration element:

[image]